# Overloading a template function which can differentiate between non-static member method and other functions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, class-method

```
struct A // some class
{
  void method(); // non-static member method
  static void function(); // static member method
};
void function(); // global function
vector<A> vi; // any such `std` like container
```

I want to have a function (say `Iterate()`) which can be called in below way:

```
Iterate(vi, &A::method);  // (1)
Iterate(vi, &A::function); // (2a)
Iterate(vi, &function); // (2b)
```

(2a) and (2b) are just identical.

Now `Iterate()` prototype looks like below for (1) and (2):

```
template<typename Container, typename Method>
void Iterate (Container &container, Method method); // for (1)

template<typename Container, typename Function>
void Iterate (Container &container, Function function); // for (2a), (2b)
```

Naturally both are exactly same, which results in compiler error.
Is there a way to overload/specialize `Iterate()` in C++03 which will allow both the function to co-exist ?

Comment: How is `Iterate` different from `std::for_each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make one function more specific than the  other:

```
template<typename Container, typename Functor>
void Iterate (Container &container, Functor fun); 

template<typename Container, typename R, typename ..Args>
void Iterate (Container &container, R (Container::value_type::*fun)(Args...));
```

The first template would work for regular functions, function-objects, and static member functions, while the second one woukd work only for non-static member function.

In C++03, you could simulate variadic template by writing overloads as shown here:

```
template<typename Container, typename R>
void Iterate (Container &container, R (Container::value_type::*fun)());

template<typename Container, typename R, typename Arg>
void Iterate (Container &container, R (Container::value_type::*fun)(Arg));

template<typename Container, typename R, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
void Iterate (Container &container, R (Container::value_type::*fun)(Arg1, Arg2));

//add more overloads to handle member functions 
//that take 3 or more arguments
```

Of course, if you have to implement them differently. For example, the syntax to invoke the member function will be `(obj.*fun)(a1,a2,a3);` while the functor invocation syntax is just `fun(a1,a2,a2)`. I don't know though what arguments you would pass to the function (member or functor). I assume this is not the real code, you just want to explore the syntax.

One important point is that `obj` (from the container) is **not** needed to invoke the functor, you could pass it as argument to it, though.

Comment: For C++ 2003 you need to overload the member function version for each number of arguments supported. In your example you used a member function taking only the implicit object as argument and functions taking no instead of one aegument. Thus, it isn't quite clear what you want to pass as arguments.

Comment: I tried the C++03 solution. Wrote a simple [test program](http://ideone.com/QSJxQi), which is not compiling. Is anything missed ? For simplicity I have assumed `typename R` to be `void`.

Comment: @iammilind: `function(*it)` would not work, as it doesn't take argument. `function()` would work . See yourself : http://ideone.com/fB5z7b

Comment: Oops, that was a typo from my side. Accepted the answer.